# can't select from mariadb table InnoDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, innodb, nextcloud

So I have a mariadb on a InnoDB engine with some tables

```
MariaDB [nextcloud]> SELECT TABLE_NAME,  ENGINE   FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE table_schema = 'nextcloud' and 
table_name LIKE 'oc_file%';
+-----------------------+--------+
| TABLE_NAME            | ENGINE |
+-----------------------+--------+
| oc_filecache_extended | InnoDB |
| oc_filecache          | InnoDB |
| oc_file_locks         | InnoDB |
| oc_files_trash        | InnoDB |
+-----------------------+--------+
```

the selects on all tables are workin fine however when I try to select from `oc_filecache` I get the following error message

```
MariaDB [nextcloud]> select * from oc_filecache;
ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 1877 "Unknown error 1877" from storage engine InnoDB
```

Do you have any Idea what this error could mean, how I could fix it or how I could get something like an extended log to pin down the problem?

The odd thing is that after I restart the container running the db, everything works fine again for some time.

Comment: Are you running owncloud? (see: [ownCloud MySQL table “oc_filecache” corrupt, can I regenerate it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1229612/owncloud-mysql-table-oc-filecache-corrupt-can-i-regenerate-it) )

Comment: Do you have any abnormal configuration of your MariaDB instance(s)?  What does `SHOW TABLE STATUS` say?

Comment: @Luuk thanks for the Link.. deleting all Entries from the table and rescanning the files solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Error => #1030 - Got error 1877 "Unknown error" from storage engine InnoDB

To solve this error follow the below steps

- Step 1. Go to Xampp control Panel  and click on 'Config' available
  next to Mysql.
- Step 2. Click on 'my.ini'
- Step 3. Search for 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' and increase size from
  16M to 256M
- Step 4. Search for 'innodb_log_file_size' and increase size from 5M
  to 128M
- Step 5. Restart Xampp